# Подскажите утилиту из lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Подскажите утилиту из lodash которая делает следующее

```
util(['a', 'b'],'N/A', {a: {b: 2}}); //=> 2
util (['a', 'b'], 'N/A', {c: {b: 2}}); //=> "N/A"
```

Comment: lodash.get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего вы имеете ввиду [`_get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get), правда там немного другой порядок агрументов

> _.get(object, path, [defaultValue]) 
>   Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```